# Choosing to Continue or Not Continue after Clicking on Link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to do something pretty simple: click on a link, modal pops up to continue or cancel to the link's URL, continue to the URL or cancel (essentially hide the modal). My issue is the "waiting" period when the modal pops up, when the user is prompted to continue or cancel. Right now, my code never seems to run past the first `waitForModalEvent()` call:

```
<a href="someURL" onclick='return handleClick()'> Click Here </a>


  function handleClick() {
    if (dataChanged()) {
        returnValue = false;
        displayModal();
        returnValue = waitForModalEvent();
        //never called at or past this point. Tested with alert()
        return returnValue;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  }

  var continueClicked = false;
  var cancelClicked = false;
  function waitForModalEvent() {
    while(!continueClicked && !cancelClicked) {
        waitForModalEvent(); //I know this gives the browser some troubles
    }

    if (continueClicked) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

I know this code is faulty (especially the hideous `waitForModalEvent()` recursive call that never ends). However, I'm stuck at how to resolve this, and **return true or false in `handleClick()` after the user clicks on either continue or cancel.** Is my setup using the `<a href>`'s `onclick` inherently a bad setup for what I'm trying to accomplish?

I've read up on callbacks, but can't grasp how I could use callbacks for my situation (if any). Would appreciate any sort of suggestions or insight!

Comment: Any suggestions on how to improve this question? Someone downvoted this.

Comment: simple way would be update an href in the dialog unless dialog gets used elsewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've generated an infinite loop which locks up the JavaScript event loop. Until the `while` loop finished the variables you are testing in it can never changed.

If you want to do something based on a DOM based dialogue, you have to do it with callbacks. There is no way (outside of a host environment provided function like `confirm`) to block while waiting for a user interaction.

The general approach to using callbacks here would be to *always* cancel the default action of clicking the link, and then have the callback replicate its functionality (or just put a regular link in the dialogue).

Comment: I thought long and hard about how to do all this WITHOUT canceling the default action of clicking the link. It seemed hacky to do that..

Comment: The user has clicked on a link. The default action of the link is to follow the link. You want the browser to stop and display a dialogue of some kind instead. Your desire is to prevent the default action.

Comment: I thought the `onclick` on the link could be used to modify the "default action" of the link--since whatever function is called inside `onclick` runs and returns true or false, which in turn allows the link to be followed or not.

Comment: Yes, so long as you can determine if you want to follow the link or not before the function finishes… which you can't.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to somehow "capture" a user clicking continue or cancel before that `onclick` function finishes. But I guess that's impossible...

Comment: Yes. That's what I said in the second paragraph of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this codepen for an illustration of callbacks and modal dialogues with jQuery UI:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdaRmP

```
$('button.showModal').click(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Proceed to The Dividing Line": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          location.href='http://www.thedividingline.com/';
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $('DIV.output').text('Canceled.');
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
});
```

I used an example from jQuery UI docs here: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation (some things I needed to change).

### EDIT

Now callback invokes a hyperlink.

Comment: I'm attempting to figure out how to "continue". Canceling the modal/dialog box seems pretty straightforward (thanks for the example), but I'm trying to use callbacks to continue on to the link.

Comment: I wasn't specific about this particular point in my original post, but if the link I clicked on passes parameters in the request, then I think we can't just use a `location.href`? Could we pass the event through `onclick` and then use that event when the user clicks continue on the modal/dialog box?

Comment: You can do any valid javascript code in a callback function body. If you use `location.href`, you can *append* the querystring with params. Like: `http://www.google.com.br/?q=callbacks`